# CSS-Floated elements collapsing parent element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am new to both stack**overflow** and web development, so your patience is greatly appreciated. :)
*All of the HTML and CSS minus certain irrelevant parts can be found at the very bottom.*

---

When styling HTML elements with CSS, I encountered a problem with floating elements and their parent element. The divs with the ids **nav** and **main** are contained within the div of the id **content**. The nav contains an unordered list, which will serve as a basic navigation bar of sorts, while main contains paragraphs and "meat" of the page. I wanted the paragraphs to sit on the right side of the navigation bar, so I decided to float them both. 
The CSS below was applied to these elements.

---

```
#nav {
width: 100px;
float: left;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
}

#main {
width: 600px;
float: right;
}
```

---

When I run my code in a browser, everything looks fine. The elements are positioned in their proper places. However, under closer examination using an examiner tool, my parent element with the id content has collapsed.
I unfortunately cannot post the image due to my lack of reputation. Hopefully this is enough information.
I have already searched the web for the problem, and it seems quite common among newbies such as myself. I read an article on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), and I attempted their methods for solving this problem. Unfortunately, this was to no avail. After further searching, I have been left confused. I would like to apologize for the broadness of this question. Thank you all for your time and knowledge.
Here is the HTML..

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/refreshstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>My Website</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav">
                <h3>Navigation</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="home" href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="about" href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="contacts" href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <h2>Home Page</h2>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>

            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">
                Copyright &copy;2014
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Below is the CSS...

---

```
body {
background-image: url('congruent_pentagon.png');
}
#container {
background-color: white;
width: 800px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
border-radius: 25px;
}
#header {
background-color: #66CCFF;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
border-top-right-radius:23px;
border-top-left-radius: 23px;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
margin:0;
}
#nav {
width: 100px;
float: left;
}
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0px;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #66CCFF;
}
#nav .home {
font-weight: bold;
}
#main {
width: 600px;
float: right;
}
#content {
padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
clear: both;
background-color: #B1F6CB;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: right;
border-top: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
border-bottom-right-radius: 23px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 23px;

}
```

Comment: What's your specific (relevant) HTML? Please, don't *describe* it to us, *show* it to us.

Comment: My apologies. The HTML and CSS is now at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use the css clearfix class. Define the clearfix class in your css:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

Use the clearfix class on the parent element, in your case on the #content element:

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    [...]
</div>
```

Find more infos about clearing floats in this [blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/).

Btw: welcome on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will take some time later to read through the blog post thoroughly. Hopefully this will fix my problem. Thank you very much for your time! :)